# JTable filter on DocumentListener not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, rowfilter

```
  //Registration filter
    final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(databaseModel);
    DocumentListener idListener = new DocumentListener() {

        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {

        }
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
            String searchText = txtReg.getText();
            if (searchText.length() == 0) {
              sorter.setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
              sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchText));
            }
            numberOfRecords.setText(searchTable.getRowCount() + " records");
        }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {

            }


    };
   txtReg.getDocument().addDocumentListener(idListener);
```

I'm here again with probably silly questions... :( I have a JTable I wish to filter out as I type on a textfield. After researching a bit I came up with this, but it doesn´t work! If I put the filter outside the listener with an arbitrary string as search term it works perfectly. What am I missing? Thank you!

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7968397937566078184L;
private static final JLabel numberOfRecords = new JLabel();
private static int numberOfRows;
private static DefaultTableModel databaseModel;



public GUI(DefaultTableModel database){
    setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    setLayout(new MigLayout());
    databaseModel = database;
    //Menus
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem update = new JMenuItem("Look for database updates");
    JMenuItem settings = new JMenuItem("Settings");
    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    menubar.add(file);
    file.add(update);
    file.add(settings);
    file.add(exit);
    setJMenuBar(menubar);
     //Top section
    JPanel searchSection = new JPanel();
    searchSection.setLayout(new MigLayout("w 50mm!"));
    final JTextField txtReg = new JTextField(10);
    JLabel searchID = new JLabel("Current registration:");
    JLabel lblManufacturer = new JLabel("Manufacturer");
    JComboBox cmbManufacturer = new JComboBox();
    JLabel lblType = new JLabel("Type");
    JComboBox cmbType = new JComboBox();
    //Build main window
    searchSection.add(searchID);
    searchSection.add(txtReg, "span 2");
    searchSection.add(lblManufacturer);
    searchSection.add(cmbManufacturer, "growx, span 2");
    searchSection.add(lblType);
    searchSection.add(cmbType,"growx, span 2");
    //Table
    final JTable searchTable = new JTable(databaseModel);
    //Pack table, still have to figure this one out
    int width = 0;
     for (int row = 0; row < searchTable.getRowCount(); row++) {
         TableCellRenderer renderer = searchTable.getCellRenderer(row, 2);
         Component comp = searchTable.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, 2);
         width = Math.max (comp.getPreferredSize().width, width);
     }

    searchTable.getColumn("Key").setMaxWidth(0);
    searchTable.getColumn("Key").setMinWidth(0);
    searchTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    searchTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    searchTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    searchTable.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(1);
    searchTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    numberOfRows=searchTable.getRowCount();
    JScrollPane browserSP = new JScrollPane(searchTable);
    browserSP.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 4, 4, 4));
    setTitle("AirBase");
    setSize(1300,700);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1250,650));
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //TODO Fill manufacturer box

    //Registration filter
    //TODO Fix this!
    final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(databaseModel);
    DocumentListener idListener = new DocumentListener() {

        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {

        }
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
            String searchText = txtReg.getText();
            if (searchText.length() == 0) {
              sorter.setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
              sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchText));
            }
            numberOfRecords.setText(searchTable.getRowCount() + " records");
        }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {

            }


    };
   txtReg.getDocument().addDocumentListener(idListener);
    add(searchSection, "w 100%, h 5%, wrap");
    add(browserSP,"w 100%, h 95%, wrap");
    numberOfRecords.setFont(numberOfRecords.getFont().deriveFont(9.0f));
    numberOfRecords.setText(numberOfRows + " RECORDS");
    add(numberOfRecords, "alignx center");
}



}
```

Comment: What you have looks fine at first glance. Can you provide a complete runnable example with hard coded values for the table so we can test it out.

Comment: @peeskillet Edited on the question, is that what you're after? :( Should I be ashamed of my code? haha

Comment: Kinda, but you're missing the data for the table model. Actually you're missing the whole table model that you pass to the frame

Comment: I should mention that the table model gets generated on startup from a database that isn´t supposed to be modified. The table loads just fine, with around 30k entries :)

Comment: That't what I meant by hard coded values. Since we can't test your database code, make a complete _runnable/compilable_ example with hard coded value for your table model, a `main` method, and you're good to go. Other than that, I created a dummy TableModel and tried to run your program and got some exceptions on startup. That's why it's important to create a runnable example for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up getting it started. Looks like a simple mistake. You forgot the `setRowSorter` for the table.

```
searchTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Added that code an it works for me. Should work for you two, give you have a valid `TableModel` passed to the `GUI`. I just made up a dummy one.

**NOTES:**

- You'll probably want to add the filter code to `removeUpdate` also, in the `DocumentListener` so when text is <kbd>backspace</kbd>'d, it will still filter.
- This `searchTable.getColumn("Key").setMaxWidth(0);` makes the row data not visible. Is that what you really want?
- If you want the filter to filter without case-sensitivity, you can use this

  ```
  sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + searchText));
  ```

  The `"(?i)"` is the case-insentive regex *"flag"*

Comment: works! Such a simple answer! Thank you very much, I'm glad to see that I don't seem to be too far from the solution when I run into trouble.